# How to run Thread in background of JavaFX app?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am writing an Application similar to windows' file explorer in Java (JavaFX). The program is just for practising (it is my first ever app).
It is a GUI application where you can create/modify/delete files and folders.

There's some buttons that are responsible for sending user actions. Class FileManagerController is a controller class of the main window. I want to add a feature to refresh ListView with all files in current directory in the background. Now it refreshes it only when the user does any action.[Here's how this app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs6ts.jpg).

Comment: Welcome to SO!! What stops you to start a thread? Can you post some code samples if possible?

Comment: If you are wanting to periodically poll a directory to see changes, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task/60685975#60685975 You might also want to read the [`WatchService` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice article about this here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

The highlights are the that "Java FX" way are through the use of a [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html).

You create a Task that has several housekeeping methods for life cycle and such, and you submit it to a Service for execution. The Service will work with a Thread or and Executor Service.

You want to use a Task because it's FX specific. As it says in the documentation:

> Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it
> ensures that every change to its public properties, as well as change
> notifications for state, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on
> the main JavaFX application thread.

From the article and the documentation, here is a simple example:

```
 public static class FirstLineService extends Service<String> {
     private StringProperty url = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "url");
     public final void setUrl(String value) { url.set(value); }
     public final String getUrl() { return url.get(); }
     public final StringProperty urlProperty() { return url; }

     protected Task createTask() {
         final String _url = getUrl();
         return new Task<String>() {
             protected String call() throws Exception {
                 URL u = new URL(_url);
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
                 String result = in.readLine();
                 in.close();
                 return result;
             }
         };
     }
 }
```

Once create, you invoke it with:

```
service.start();
```

Comment: AIUI the OP wants to repeatedly poll a folder to update if there are changes. A simple `Service` is probably not the right tool for this job; either a `ScheduledService`, or simply a `Thread` constantly monitoring a `WatchKey` are more likely to be better equipped for this.

Comment: That's right. I want to monitor changes in actual directory and that is why I used poll with 100 milis. The problem is how to send information to the FX Thread to refresh ListView?